# Java - Hibernate3 JAR source attached

Tags: java, json, hibernate

I am looking for Hibernate3 jar with source attached. Looked everywhere did not find it.

Anybody has idea where i can look for it?

Thanks
Fahad Mullaji

Answer (score 2):

You can get the source file by downloading the jar that contains source code.

Check this link for hibernate-core source code:

[hibernate-core-4.3.6.Final-sources.jar](https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public-jboss/org/hibernate/hibernate-core/4.3.6.Final/)

Comment: Well the link did not give me what i wanted but when i downloaded version 4.3.6 from source forge, i got source code from there. Thanks for suggesting this version!!!!

Answer (score 0):

GrepCode is perfect for locating any jar you can think of.

This is hibernate3.jar link:

http://grepcode.com/snapshot/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.hibernate/hibernate/3.5.4-Final